# Logging by Username or Email when using two entities with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUSerBundle with two different Entities for different Users like
DefaultUser and AdminUser

Therefore I have the following in security.yaml

```
    providers:
    user:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: 'email'
    admin:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:Admin
            property: 'email'
```

and firewall is set like this:

```
 admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            anonymous: ~
            provider: admin
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: /admin
                check_path: admin_login_check
            logout_on_user_change: true
            logout:
                path: /admin/logout
                target: /admin
                invalidate_session: false
            access_denied_handler: AppBundle\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
            context: application

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: user
            logout_on_user_change: true

            form_login:
#                csrf_token_generatlor: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path: /login
                default_target_path: /user
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                  path:           user_logout
                  target:         user_login
                  invalidate_session: false

            context:         application
            anonymous:    ~
            access_denied_handler: AppBundle\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
```

**How to get FOSUserBundle work, so I can use username or Email ?**

Normally it is set by

```
id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

but this cannot used in this configuration.

Comment: property: 'username_email' does not work

Comment: With your current configuration you're not really using FOSUserBundle because you're not using the bundle's provider (i.e. `fos_user.user_provider.username_email` ) ... but symfony's builtin entity-provider. So what's the question exactly? FOSUserBundle doesn't support multiple user entities to login with by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I worked with the fos_userbundle, but from what I see in my code, you'll need to update your security.yml file to make use of it:

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle_admin: appbundle.service.providing.admin_user
```

And in that service (which extends `FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider`), you'll want to override the `findUser($username)` method. There, you can use the provided username.

I suppose (untested) you can create another provider (fos_userbundle_user) and use that one for users in your firewall.

Hopefully this makes sense.. It's working here, but that was in a symfony 2.8 app. FOS_UserBundle has changed a fair bit since then.